# Oracle DB create directory

Tags: sql, oracle, file, directory

I am trying to create directory is SQL Developer and create a simple text file there using this code :

```
CREATE DIRECTORY ABC AS '/abc';


    DECLARE
      fileHandler UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    BEGIN
      fileHandler := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('ABC', 'test_file.txt', 'W');
      UTL_FILE.PUTF(fileHandler, 'Writing to a file\n');
      UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fileHandler);
    END;
```

But it ends up with that Error

```
29283. 00000 -  "invalid file operation"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does
           not exist, or file or directory access was denied by the
           operating system.
*Action:   Verify file and directory access privileges on the file system,
           and if reading, verify that the file exists.
```

In SQL developer the directory variable is created and visible

So, my question is Does that piece of code suppose to create directory by itself or do i have to create it manually? (I don't have access to the servers file system)

Comment: According to the documentation, `FOPEN` will create the file if it doesn't exist. However, it can only create files in directories where it has write access. Have you tried providing the complete file path?

Comment: but the directory /abc doesn't exits so i was wondering if 
CREATE DIRECTORY ABC AS '/abc'; will create one or is it only making a variable pointing to directory that should be created manually

Comment: It creates a new directory with the mentioned name.

Comment: @user3102664 It would create one at the server where database is mounted. You can check that in data dictionary `dba_directories`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like `GRANTS` are missing.

To create a directory:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY alias AS 'pathname';
```

Where:

```
alias is the name of the directory alias.

pathname is the physical directory path.
```

To Grant:

```
GRANT permission ON DIRECTORY alias TO {user | role | PUBLIC};
```

Where:

permission is one of the following:

```
READ for read-only access

WRITE for write-only access

ALL for read and write access

alias is the name of the directory alias.

user is a database user name.
```

Edit:

Directory Check:

```
SQL> SELECT DIRECTORY_NAME , DIRECTORY_PATH FROM DBA_DIRECTORIES WHERE DIRECTORY_NAME = 'BDUMP';

DIRECTORY_NAME                 DIRECTORY_PATH
------------------------------ ---------------
BDUMP                          /home/fil_test/
```

Change directory permission. By default it has only Read and execute permission for others.

```
terminal$ chmod 777 fil_test
```

Block:

```
DECLARE
   fHandle   UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
   fHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('BDUMP', 'test_file', 'w');

   UTL_FILE.PUT (fHandle, 'This is the first line');
   UTL_FILE.PUT (fHandle, 'This is the second line');
   UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (fHandle, 'This is the third line');

   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (fHandle);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
         'Exception: SQLCODE=' || SQLCODE || '  SQLERRM=' || SQLERRM);
      RAISE;
END;
/
Execution:

SQL> @tt.sql

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

And i See the file created:

```
terminal$ ls -lrt test_file*
-rw-r-----   1 oracle   dba           68 Oct 24 14:49 test_file
```

Comment: Ok so i Did this


-GRANT WRITE ON DIRECTORY ABC TO SOME_USER;


-Grant succeeded.

But the effect of earlier query is same

Comment: can you see your directory in `DBA_DIRECTORIES` table.

Comment: Yes sir, Owner SYS

Comment: Thanks that was that! Love it